# WPF ControlTemplate for nesting

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to create a Template for my ContextMenu, which I can reuse as a child for some of my ContextMenu entries:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Name="StatusContextMenu" x:Key="StatusContextMenu">
    <MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="BLA" />
    </MenuItem>
</ControlTemplate>

<ContextMenu x:Shared="false" x:Key="SysTrayMenu">
    <MenuItem Header="Online" Command="{Binding SetStatusOnlineCommand}" Template="{StaticResource StatusContextMenu}" />
    <MenuItem Header="Away" Command="{Binding SetStatusAbwesendCommand}" Template="{StaticResource StatusContextMenu}" />
</ContextMenu>
```

Using the ControlTemplate my Headers are empty, but at least every MenuItem has the "Bla"-Child ... I want to achieve this structure:

```
- Online
   - Bla
- Away
   - Bla
```

I will replace "Bla" with the last 10 statustext for the specific status. AND a textbox at the top to set a new statustext. 
The statustexts will differ for Online and Away.

Everything is declared inside a ResourceDictionary

My Question is:
How to create a template to reuse in XAML several times?!

Comment: Instead of adding `Bla` to every `MenuItem`, would it not be a good idea to instead place `Bla` at the top level? (Where `Online` and `Away` are)

Comment: The final result will offer the user his 10 last statustexts + a textbox to add a new Statustext for his online/Away Status. I added this info to the original post for clarification

Comment: This reads more like the first entry in a blog.  What's your question?

Comment: I edited the post: My Question is: How to create a template to reuse in XAML several times?